# Host website on UNIX, but email on Windows?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, php, htaccess, email

Client has web hosting and email hosting from one web provider.

Their email hosting is integrated with their systems for their office — an Exchange server (located on their premises).

Both are on a Windows server (the same one, TBC — security problem?), but this web host does not support PHP, a problem for:

- WordPress on a subdirectory
- PHP contact form scripts
- PHP includes

Nor does it support .htaccess — a problem for things that I have built into the site:

- Redirects/404
- [Various other enhancements](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess)

Client has agreed to move the website over to either a UNIX server with the same web host, or I can also suggest another (cheaper/better) one.

The email can remain hosted on the Windows server (as I understand Exchange will not work on Apache).

Will it be possible to seamlessly and easily do this? Likely by changing A/CNAME/NS/MX settings for the domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Email hosting is easy to separate out from web hosting using DNS. In that case, you would point the `MX` records to the email host, and the records for the main domain name and `www` to the web host.

*So what should you do?*

In your case, you should be able to separate out the web hosting from the email by changing just the `A` record for the main domain to a new IP address of the UNIX host. In this case, you'd leave the `MX` records alone.